# Translate TCP binary to human readable

Tags: tcp, binary, wireshark

By using Wireshark, I want to read the conversation between my machine (using MetaTrader) and the Meta trader server. It's a TCP conversation but unfortunately I couldn't decode the binary parsed (I tried base64 decode and others things by playing with hex but nothing worked).

Any way/idea to decode this conversation ?

Big thanks in advance for your time/reply
Respectfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly going to be impossible without going to extreme measures requiring deep knowledge. Unless the protocol was designed by a complete imbecile, the information will be encrypted so just trying to decode it by observation is extremely unlikely to have any hope of working at all.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help ! I will think about other ways to map the content sent and received between my client and the server. Have a nice end of week !